# Any command for group products?

Tags: linear-algebra, permutation, group-theory

Is there any Mathematica command or well known technique to take the direct product between two symmetric/permutation groups?

Comment: can you give example?

Comment: Look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109860/generating-abstract-group-from-direct-product-of-two-abstract-groups/109874#109874)