# Generating abstract group from direct product of two abstract groups

Tags: group-theory

In group theory one can calculate some abstract groups through the direct product of two other abstract groups. An example for such a generation is the product $A_5\times Z_2$ with order 120, or $Z_4\times Z_2$ with order 8.

Since the abstract group representation in *Mathematica* is a permutation group one could have the idea to use the outer product with `PermutationProduct` on the group elements of two multiplied groups to generate the group product as

```
GroupOrder[
     PermutationGroup[Flatten[Outer[PermutationProduct,
         GroupElements[grpA],
         GroupElements[grpB]
     ]]]
]
```

which yields the correct order (120) for `grpA = AlternatingGroup[5]` and `grpB = CyclicGroup[2]` but too high an order (24) for `grpA = CyclicGroup[4]` and `grpB = CyclicGroup[2]`.

One gets the similar result when trying to generate the direct product through using the generators of the two multiplied groups as

```
GroupOrder[
 PermutationGroup[
  Join[
   GroupGenerators[grpA], 
   GroupGenerators[grpB]
  ]
 ]
]
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***tl;dr:*** The cycles of `group1` and `group2` should not involve the same values. The simplest way to obtain a direct product is to use the function [`FiniteGroupData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FiniteGroupData.html) with the syntax

> FiniteGroupData[ { *"DirectProduct"*, { $group_1$, $group_2$, ...} }, 
>                      *"PermutationGroupRepresentation"*]

---

**From the examples**

The issue can be found by noticing that $Z_2 \times Z_4$ can be represented as `AbelianGroup[{2, 4}]`, and by comparing the group elements

```
GroupElements@AbelianGroup[{2, 4}]

(* {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{3, 4, 5, 6}}], Cycles[{{3, 5}, {4, 6}}], 
    Cycles[{{3, 6, 5, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 2}}], Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 6}}], 
    Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}}], Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 6, 5, 4}}]} *)
```

to those obtained from the `PermutationProduct` of $Z_2$ and $Z_4$

```
Flatten@ Outer[PermutationProduct,
     GroupElements[CyclicGroup[2]],
     GroupElements[CyclicGroup[4]]]

(* {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 3}, {2, 4}}], 
    Cycles[{{1, 4, 3, 2}}], Cycles[{{1, 2}}], Cycles[{{1, 3, 4}}], 
    Cycles[{{1, 4, 2, 3}}], Cycles[{{2, 4, 3}}]} *)
```

To get the correct elements, we can replace `GroupElements[CyclicGroup[4]]` by `GroupElements[CyclicGroup[4]] /. Thread[Range[4] -> Range[3, 6]]`,

```
cycles = Flatten@Outer[PermutationProduct, 
     GroupElements[CyclicGroup[2]], 
     GroupElements[CyclicGroup[4]] /. Thread[Range[4] -> Range[3, 6]]];

cycles === GroupElements[AbelianGroup[{2, 4}]]

(* True *)
```

which has the correct group order

```
GroupOrder[PermutationGroup[cycles]]

(* 8 *)
```

**Generalization**

For the direct product of two arbitrary groups, a possible approach could be (see alternative *(b)* below for a simplest way)

```
directProduct[group1_, group2_] := With[
     {order1 = GroupOrder[group1], order2 = GroupOrder[group2]},

     PermutationGroup[Flatten@Outer[PermutationProduct,
           GroupElements[group1],
           GroupElements[group2] /. Thread[Range[order2] -> (order1 + Range[order2])]]]
]
```

For $Z_2 \times Z_4$:

```
directProduct[CyclicGroup[2], CyclicGroup[4]]
% // GroupOrder

(* PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{}], Cycles[{{3, 4, 5, 6}}], 
  Cycles[{{3, 5}, {4, 6}}], Cycles[{{3, 6, 5, 4}}], Cycles[{{1, 2}}], 
  Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 6}}], Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}}], 
  Cycles[{{1, 2}, {3, 6, 5, 4}}]}] *)

(* 8 *)
```

**Alternatives**

*(a)* A similar workaround can be applied from the `GroupGenerators`

```
directProduct2[group1_, group2_] := PermutationGroup[Join[
     GroupGenerators[group1], 
     GroupGenerators[group2] /. Cycles[l_] :> Cycles[l + PermutationMax[group1]]
]]
```

For $Z_2 \times Z_4$:

```
directProduct2[CyclicGroup[2], CyclicGroup[4]]
% // GroupOrder

(* PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 2}}], Cycles[{{3, 4, 5, 6}}]}] *)
(* 8 *)
```

In both approaches, one should make sure that the cycles of `group1` and those of `group2` do not involve the same values.

*(b)* A simpler way to go, equivalent to alternative *(a)* above in terms of the cycles generated, is to use the function `FiniteGroupData`

```
FiniteGroupData[{"DirectProduct", 
                 {{"CyclicGroup", 2}, {"CyclicGroup", 4}}
                }, "PermutationGroupRepresentation"]

(* PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{1, 2}}], Cycles[{{3, 4, 5, 6}}]}] *)

FiniteGroupData[{"DirectProduct", 
                 {{"AlternatingGroup", 5}, {"CyclicGroup", 2}}
                }, "PermutationGroupRepresentation"]

(* PermutationGroup[{Cycles[{{6, 7}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 3}}], Cycles[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}]}] *)
```

Comment: I was not aware of the DirectProduct Property in Finite GroupData. It seems that this is covering even very high order of abstract groups. If I try it with AlternatingGroup of degree 10 and CyclicGroup of degree 2 I get the correct order of 3628800. I'll try out if I find any combination of abstract groups which is not covered with this, but it seems that FiniteGroupData does the trick, thanks!

Comment: one additional item @Xavier. Where did you find the FiniteGroupData command syntax on the DirectProduct? I checked with the MMA documentation and did not find it there....

Comment: @Rainer You can find it in the "Details" section of `FiniteGroupData`, second Table. Three special group specifications are shown: `"AbelianGroup"`, `"DirectProduct"` and `"SemidirectProduct".`